# Bootmgr missing after swapping hard drives - what happened?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-server-2008, boot-manager

I'm using Windows Server 2008 installed on a HP ProLiant Ml350 G6 server. It has six hard drive slots, previously only two slots were occupied with 500 GB each. Recently I filled up the remaning slots with 1TB each, but it didn't detect the hard drives.

So I tried a different method and swapped the hard drives. That didn't help. Then I inserted all the hard drives into their original slots where they were before and rebooted. I got an error about the "Bootmgr missing", and I should press `ctrl+alt+del` to restart.

Is this a hardware problem or an operating system problem?

Comment: Seems like you shouldn't have touched it. It'd help to have a bit more information, as Wil said below.

Answer (score 2):

Having a little bit of trouble understanding the environment, but It sounds like you could have messed around which drive is the boot drive.

If I was you, look in the BIOS (or EFI), or even RAID settings (I do not know your infrastructure) and see if you can change the boot device.

However, if you are sure everything should be working, try putting in a Windows Server 2008 Boot Disk and performing a system repair.

Comment: That's a message from [the PC98 bootstrap](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/windows-nt-6-boot-process.html#PC).  So it isn't an EFI system.